# Proving two Hilbert Spaces are Isomorphic

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces

Suppose I have two vector spaces $V$ and $W$. I know $W$ is a Hilbert space. I want to show $V$ is a Hilbert space by showing $V$ is isomorphic to $W$.

I have

- Identified a bijection $T$ between $V$ and $W$
- Shown my bijection $T$ preserves vector space operations (I showed the bijection is linear).
- Shown my bijection preserves the inner product (so $\langle T(x), T(y) \rangle_{V} = \langle x, y \rangle_{W}$ for all $x, y \in W$).

In an example in class, my professor added that we should check the continuity of $T$ and $T^{-1}$. I was wondering why as it doesn't currently fit my working definition of an isomorphism.

I have tried to do some digging online. I came across the term homomorphism a lot, but I'm not sure if it's relevant to my problem. For context, the $V$ and $W$ that I am working with are $V = \{f_{S}\colon \mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}\colon x\mapsto \langle S, xx^{\intercal}\rangle_{F} \text{ where }S \in \mathbb{S}^{n\times n}\}$ and $W = \mathbb{S}^{n\times n}$.

Note: I have already seen this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3638104/showing-that-two-hilbert-spaces-are-isomorphic). I don't think it captures the scope of my question.

Thanks!

Comment: "Preserves inner product" should be $\langle x,y\rangle_V = \langle T(x),T(y)\rangle_W$: the images of $T$ lie in $W$, not $V$.

Comment: What you’re describing is a surjective linear isometric, which is far stronger than the concept of an isomorphism. You can check that $\|Tx\| =\|x\|$ for all $x$, hence $T$ is continuous. This works similarly for $T^{-1}$ too.

Comment: If we are talking about finite dimensional Hilbert Spaces, any linear bijection is an isomorphism.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes, good catch! Thanks!

Comment: @TheoBendit Thank you! Just checking my understanding: I showed $V$ is isomorphic to $W$ with the bijection. Steps 2 and 3 made my bijection a surjective linear isometric?

Comment: @SilentMath Thanks! Yes, I'm working with finite-dimensional Hilbert Spaces. So, when I did steps 1 and 2, I had already found the isomorphism?

Comment: Yes @bandicoot12

Comment: @SilentMath Thanks! Regarding my original question, is it necessary to show $T$ and $T^{-1}$ are continuous? From TheoBendit's observation, I guess $T$ and $T^{-1}$ will always be continuous?

Comment: Yes, they will always be continuous.

Comment: Regarding your response to my comment @bandicoot12, yes that's right, except that the surjective part arrives from step 1. The distinction of *surjective* isometry is important, as isometries need not be surjective, however a surjective isometry is automatically injective.